# How to delete stale data asp.net mvc code first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have developed an asp.net mvc application using entityFramewrok, code first in my app I have a class which maps to a table with the following property

```
public class Comments
 {
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastEdit{ get; set; }

}
```

I want my app be able to delete(remove) comments which are older that 40 days automatically.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the class you posted or with ASP.NET, or MVC, or even Entity Framework really.  This is just about scheduling a task to run each day, which will identify data and delete it.

Essentially you have two primary options...

1) Create a Windows Service.  This would include a `Timer` which is set to execute every 24 hours (or any other interval you see fit).  The action invoked by that `Timer` would connect to the database, identify the records to be deleted, and delete them.

2) Create a Console Application.  This wouldn't internally run any kind of schedule, but would just perform a one-time action of connecting to the database, identifying the records to be deleted, and deleting them.  This application would be scheduled to run periodically (again, every day sounds reasonable) using the host system's task scheduler.

It would make sense to use the same Entity Framework code that the web application uses, so you would want to make sure that code is in its own Class Library project and then both the Web Application and the Windows Service would reference that project.

Conversely, if you *need* to keep this local to the web application itself, then the application would need to do this in response to a request of some kind.  That would hurt performance of the application, but it's still possible.  Any time a user requests a given page you can first perform those deletes and then return the requested view.  Again, this is *not ideal* because it means doing this many times a day and interrupting the user experience (even for just a moment).  It's best to offload background data maintenance to an offline application, such as a Windows Service or a Console Application.

Comment: what about libraries like https://fluentscheduler.codeplex.com/ or http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ ? vs Windows Service ?

Comment: @1AmirJalali: Those may work as well, sure.  At an architectural level I still recommend separating the concerns into different applications.  Keep in mind that a web server (IIS in this case, most likely) can "stop" a web application as part of its own resource management.  In general, web applications aren't reliable means of running scheduled tasks.  They *can*, but it's not as reliable.

Comment: where does sql server job stand in this equation?

Comment: You may want to consider something like the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project for scheduling web callbacks for your ASP.NET MVC project. Using _Revalee_ would allow you to schedule a 'clean-up comments action' 40 days in the future right from within your MVC application. This would allow you to centralize all of your code in your MVC app without having to have any external processes, like a scheduled SQL job, perform the clean-up.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can create trigger in database for this.

**2.** As David say, using Windows Service or Console Application create a applications that connects to database and do something like this:

```
public void DeleteOldComments()
{
  var monthAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
  var oldComments = Db.CommentsTable.Where(e => e.DateTime <= monthAgo);
  foreach (var item in oldComments )
  {
      var e = Db.CommentsTable.Find(item.Id);
      if (e != null)
      {
           Db.CommentsTable.Remove(e);
      }
  }
}
```

**3. Long and bad way:** Create settings table, and save **LastCommentDeleteDate** there, in your site layout, using javascript call any action that fire `DeleteOldComments()` one time in a day. (using cookie). In any request check **LastCommentDeleteDate**, if it allowed, call delete function.